# Order independent hashing

Tags: c++, hash, crypto++

I'm creating keys for key-value data by taking a few (<10) pieces of information that identify the data and producing one hash from them combined. For this, I've been using CryptoPP's `SHA256::Update` function, which lets you add pieces at a time:

```
#include "sha.h"
...
byte outputBuf[CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE];
CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;
hash.Update(pData1, lenData1); // pData* can point to int, double or std::string
hash.Update(pData2, lenData2);
...
hash.Final(outputBuf);
```

I've noticed that the order of the calls to `Update` matters (i.e. if you change the order of the two `Update` statements, you'll get a different hash). I would like this to be order independent instead. So:

- Does CryptoPP offer a way to do this?
- If not, can you suggest an alternative approach? So far I think using `xor` to combine the  parameters would work. One problem is that if two pieces of data are the same, they'll cancel out. Can you foresee problems with this?

Comment: I'm curious why you want order independence.  If your data are homogeneous and have the same structure, why not enforce that each one is fed to the hash function in the same way, with the same bits of information in the same order each time?

Comment: Almost every good hash (even non-cryptographic) will be order-dependent. Otherwise it will cause foreseeable collisions in a very regular pattern, which is no good.

Comment: `+` has no canceling, not sure about security. Ensuring consistent order seems to be better idea.

Comment: @Omaha: It's not a hard requirement, but I wanted to make it order independent so mistakes are less likely. I can easily imagine two lines of code getting switched around on accident by someone down the line. Also, the identifying info doesn't really have an intrinsic ordering; I'd be picking an arbitrary one that might not be meaningful down the line as things change.

Comment: @Damon I know that it would slightly increase chances of collisions, but with a 256 bit hash you still have a very big address space.

Comment: Do a single hash on each chunk of data independently, then `^` the results together.  Sure, it is horrible and lacks many features you want in a good hash, but it is a hash that is order independent.

Comment: Just provide a function taking named arguments (or a structure with named members) and let the function worry about what order to hash them in. Any way of making the hash order-independent will increase collisions, perhaps quite significantly.

Comment: Order independence will not just _sightly_ increase the number of collisions, but significantly (since there are N! permutations for N bytes, and 20! is something around 10^18). But worse, as already mentioned, there are not only collisions, but they happen in a pattern. Also note that the "disadvantage" of using xor as a hash is present for every commutative operation. The inverse element will always cancel out. With xor, this happens to be an identical block, but it's the same (with some different value) for every commutative operation (e.g. `a + b + (-b) = a`) . That's just how it works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be better suited for crypto.stackexchange.com or security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

The comment saying that xor will increase the number of collisions is only true, if you consider `{1, 2}` and `{2, 1}` to be *different* inputs. I guess, you don't, as otherwise you wouldn't want an order-independent hash. So `h({1, 2}) = h({2, 1})` is no collision as you're providing *the same input*.

The simplest solution is sorting and than using your favorite hash function. It is as *secure* as your hash function (confirm on crypto.stackexchange.com if you care).

Xoring hashes is definitely a bad idea as two equal elements cancel out. Adding them is much better, but with two equal elements, the least significant bit will be zero (with four such elements, two bits will be zero, etc.). This may be acceptable.

Note that any such method is pretty insecure as it allows finding collisions much faster (proof upon request). You may or may not need security, but don't try to invent a secure method, as it's practically impossible (every well-known hash function has many man-months of analysis behind it).